# How can I implement observer pattern on my own without notification centre in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

This question was asked by someone & not able to find the solution for this
How can I implement my own observer pattern without notification centre?

Comment: Do you mean KVO?

Answer (score 4):

I would just use the same basic pattern as `NotificationCenter`. Have a way to add and remove observers and a way to tell them when a notification has occurred. Something like this:

```
class MyNotification {
    var notificationName: String
    init(name: String) {
        notificationName = name
    }
}

protocol MyObserver {
    func processNotification(notification: MyNotification);
}

class MyNotificationCenter {
    var observers : [MyObserver] = []

    func addObserver(observer: MyObserver) {
        // Add the observer to the array
    }

    func removeObserver(observer: MyObserver) {
        // Remove the observer from the array
    }

    func postNotification(notification: MyNotification) {
        // For each object in the observer array, call its processNotification() method
    }
}
```

Note that this is simplified. It assumes all observers are watching for all notifications. If you want to do something more sophisticated then you'd want a dictionary that maps notification types to observers and only notify the observers that are watching for the specific notification that was posted. You'd probably also want to have more data go into a `notification` so that an `observer` can do something useful with it.